# Spring Boot Oauth Refresh Token

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I have implemented access token and refresh token expiry in my  auth application.As my access token expires I hit a refresh token request.I get a new access token,but also a new refresh token gets generated.I want the refresh token to remain the same till it's expiration time.

```
clients.inMemory()
        .withClient(clientId).secret(secretKey)
        .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token").scopes("read","write")
        .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT", "USER","ADMIN")
        .autoApprove(true)
        .accessTokenValiditySeconds(Integer.parseInt(accessTokenValidityInSeconds))
        .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(Integer.parseInt(refreshTokenValidityInSeconds));
```

Comment: then you need to alter the back-end. Have it return the same tokenId until expiration, but, if you do that, the expiration time will be prolonged, since it's a new token. You would have the same refresh token id indefinitely